# Identify this gray spider with distinctive white mark

Tags: species-identification

I was out back in the garden tonight and found an extremely long strand of web running about 10 ft. At the end was a kind of spider I’ve never seen before. It’s about a .75-1 inch, fat body, with a distinctive white mark on its back. It was very docile while I took the pic. I’m in Austin, TX and this was night time. Any clues?[image]

Comment: An Orb Weaver - I dont know what sort. Giant lichen?